# Get product name using expression in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, telr

I can get Order ID using the expression {order_id} like the screenshot below.

Is there any expression by which I can get the product name just like Order Id. This is a payment gateway plugin so editing the plugin files would be the last thing I want to do. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some intellectuals have down voted my question without giving any glimpse of their knowledge base. But for some poors like me, Here's what i found :

file: plugins/telr/class-wc-gateway-telr-checkout-handler.php

method: private function generate_request($order)

find:

```
$cart_desc = trim(wc_gateway_telr()->settings->__get('cart_desc'));
if (empty($cart_desc)) {
    $cart_desc ='Order {order_id}';
}
$cart_desc  = preg_replace('/{order_id}/i', $order_id, $cart_desc);
add_post_meta($order_id, '_telr_cartdesc', $cart_desc);
```

replace with:

```
$cart_desc = trim(wc_gateway_telr()->settings->__get('cart_desc'));
if (empty($cart_desc)) {
    $cart_desc ='Order {order_id}';
}

$order_items = $order->get_items();
$productNames = array();
foreach ($order_items as $product_data) {
    $productInfo = $product_data->get_data();
    $productNames[] = $productInfo['name'];
}
$cartProducts = implode(", ", $productNames);
$cart_desc  = preg_replace('/{order_id}/i', $order_id, $cart_desc);
$cart_desc  = preg_replace('/{product_names}/i', $cartProducts, $cart_desc);
$cart_desc = substr($cart_desc, 0, 63);
add_post_meta($order_id, '_telr_cartdesc', $cart_desc);
```

after this, {product_names} will be replaced by ',' separated product names & final description string will be trimmed until 63 characters (as that is the length that a description can have)